# Obtendo propriedade específica de um objeto JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Eu tenho o seguinte JSON:

```
 {
  "2016": {
    "mes": {
      "2": {
        "dia": {
          "5": {
            "-KcENENmSJcZp56clzz5": {
              "descricao": "teste",
              "valor": "99"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "2017": {
    "mes": {
      "2": {
        "dia": {
          "5": {
            "-KcELskoSWWttptIgb0L": {
              "descricao": "xx",
              "valor": "55"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "$id": "ano",
  "$priority": null
}
```

Isto é um retorno do firebase, eu gostaria por exemplo pegar o valor `2016`.

Uso o angular para popular uma lista assim:

```
<li ng-repeat="gasto in gastos"> 

</li>
```

Se dentro da minha tag `li` eu utilizar `{{gasto.$id}}` imprime `"ano"` e eu não to sabendo pegar o valor `2016` por exemplo.

Comment: se você fizer {{ gasto['2016'] }} ele vai retornar o json: "mes": {
      "2": {
        "dia": {
          "5": {
            "-KcENENmSJcZp56clzz5": {
              "descricao": "teste",
              "valor": "99"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

Comment: @JuniorNunes é isso mesmo irmão, publica a resposta para eu marcar pra você

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você vai conseguir pegar assim:

```
{{ gasto['2016'] }}
```

Resultado:

```
"mes": {
  "2": {
    "dia": {
      "5": {
        "-KcENENmSJcZp56clzz5": {
          "descricao": "teste",
          "valor": "99"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```